# Access to the path denied when try to change creation date

Tags: powershell

I am fresh user of Powershell scripting. Tried to stackoverflow beforehand but didnt found the exact solution although been copying and trying to understand several solutions but I guess they were more of personal fit rather than global solutions

I would like to change creation and later on - modification date

Firstly I went to the directory I wanted which is `DATAMAP` on my desktop using cd function, then I try to change a file creation date by using

```
(Get-Item my_filename.mp4).creationtime=$(Get-Date "01/02/2016 10:09 am")
```

The error I get is

```
    Exception setting "creationtime": "Access to the path
'C:\Users\mycpu\Desktop\MAPDATA\my_filename.mp4' is denied."
At line:1 char:1
+ (Get-Item my_filename.mp4).creati ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], SetValueInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ExceptionWhenSetting
```

Tried several formats, but my windows format date (short) is 03/05/2021 as for now

Any suggestions?

Comment: Is your Powershell open as Admin?

Comment: Just to sanity check, in the description you said the folder was called `DATAMAP` but then in the sample code, you have `MAPDATA`.  I can't replicate it on a file on my own desktop.

Comment: My bad, its MAPDATA. Yes i do right click on windows icon -> Windows Powershell (admin)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Works for me.  Maybe the file has attrib set to read only?

```
(get-item file).creationtime = get-date '1/2/16 10:09'
get-item file | % creationtime

Saturday, January 2, 2016 10:09:00 AM
```

Comment: Hi. It works! I think it might be "am/pm" suffix to the time. Wonder why "access time" does not change though - `(get-item my_filename.mp4).lastaccesstime = get-date '1/2/17 10:09'
>> get-item my_filename.mp4 | % lastaccesstime

01 February 2017 10:09:00` but in the properties it still shows current date

Comment: The time format shouldn't matter.  Everything works for me.

Comment: It work for me when it comes to creationtime and lastwriteteam but completly nothing when it comes to lastaccesstime - any suggestions?